# Crypto-js AES encryption in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, aes, cryptojs

`crypto-js` has a semi-well known problem. It doesn't check the key size when doing `AES` encryption. And the problem is that an api made by a company uses a `crypto-js` encrypted string as a request. And it uses a 43byte key as the encryption key, which doesn't make any sense.

But I want to encrypt the string in python, which doesn't have any library that can encrypt AES with 43bytes (of course, because it should be normally impossible). So is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: crypto-js does not have a problem, it's just the user or programmer that can't read the docs properly :-) The docs (https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) say: *For the key, when you pass a string, it's treated as a passphrase and used to derive an actual key and IV. Or you can pass a WordArray that represents the actual key. If you pass the actual key, you must also pass the actual IV.* means: if you don't feed the "key" as a WordArray it is used to **derive** the encryption key and iv from the given **passphrase** - just like e.g. OpenSSL does.

Comment: Search for "EVP_BytesToKey" for python and you will find a python key derivation function.

Comment: There is indeed this bug that CryptoJS performs encryption even with non-AES  compliant key lengths, resulting in non-AES compatible ciphertexts that therefore usually cannot be decrypted with AES compatible libraries. However, since you are talking about a string (which is interpreted as a passphrase) and not a `WordArray` (which is interpreted as a key), this bug is most likely not the cause, but a misunderstanding on your part, as described in the previous comment.